# Guice integration-test approach

Tags: java, junit, guice

I'm a bit struggle to find the working solution for integration tests for Guice-based application.

It's slightly more complicated than HelloWorld examples on Guice doc.

The idea is to provide junit-extension for injecting all dependencies (like a real application) but I need to re-inject some modules in `beforeEach` while I also need to support injector creation logic in `beforeAll` where I need to bind some severe db-like modules, queues.

The biggest issue is a proper way to handle not-closed connections for modules instantiated in `beforeAll` and `after`

```
class Extension implements BeforeAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback,
        AfterAllCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    private Injector injector;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
      // modules = some havyweight modules (db, etc)
      injector = Guice.createInjector(modules);
      dbMigrate(injector);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
      // modules like mocks, time-mocks
      List<AbstractModule> newModules = Stream.concat(oldModules, tempModules).collect(Collectors.toList());
      injector = Create.createInjector(newModules); 
    }
}
```

It means that I create recreate hard-resources twice and some of them cannot be released properly.

I tried to create child injector in `beforeEach` but it doesn't work for me, because I need to rebind this modules after each test.

Could someone suggest how to cope with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to not use Guice for your unit tests at all. If you've set things up nicely, you can use the constructor injection that Guice normally does, manually in your tests. This has the advantage of only loading and starting the dependencies you need, instead of your whole application. That should make things a lot faster.

If you can't do that, then perhaps you can change your JUnit rule to create the injector on every test (in `beforeEach` instead of `beforeAll`).

Comment: Yes, I try to provide solution for integration-tests. I understand that having one construction with `Guice.createInjector` in `beforeEach` which will work for all cases. `beforeAll` I need to once per test functionality (create queues, etc.). Probably, my mistake that I try to create one Builder-managed initialzer that will work for some stubbed and others real servers with specific modules. Of course, it would be call if it's possible to re-inject and override some modules  with one Guice API call but seems that there is no such option.